# Paragraph Numbering and Alignment

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I am writing a report and looking to achieve two things;

1. paragraph numbering per paragraph of my document, e.g. 1., 2. etc.
2. bumping out the paragraph numbers as well as the section numbers into the left margin with my text and section titles aligned nicely

Because it's a large document I would like to use the "\input{example.txt}" option to pull my content into the document and ideally not have to include any "\paragraph" identifiers in the example.txt file, just blocks of text.

Anyone able to advise where I am going wrong?

I am new to Latex so feel free to point out any rookie mistakes - assume I know nothing, you wont be too far off :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newlength{\alphabet}
\settowidth{\alphabet}{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\usepackage[textwidth=2.5\alphabet]{geometry}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\newcommand{\changefontleft}{%
    \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
}
\newcommand{\changefontcenter}{%
    \fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont
}
\newcommand{\changefontright}{%
    \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE] {\thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}.}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont}{\theparagraph}{\wordsep}{}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{\wordsep}


\begin{document}

    \section{Report}

\input{input.txt}% 

    \subsection{Details}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \subsection{Garage}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Bedrooms}    
\lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{Bathrooms}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Toilets}
\lipsum[1-5]
    
    
\end{document}
```

The input.txt just contains paragraphs of plain text like so;

```
If you're an influencer or content creator, you might not think you need to worry about business plans and executive summaries. 

Executive summaries can help you convince investors, venture capitalists, and the brands you approach for partnerships and sponsorship agreements that you're worth the investment.

Executive summaries aren't written in stone.
```

Thank you

Comment: unrelated but `\fontsize{16}{11}\selectfont` is setting unachievable constraints. 16pt letters on lines that are only 11pt apart. (similar comment applies to all your settings)

Comment: It isn't clear what you intend to put in `input.txt` as you provided no example, will it be just text without any LaTeX  markup? Also `\paragraph` is a sectioning command (one level below subsubsection) so not related to paragraphs in the main text block. I suspect you do not want `\obeylines` around the `\input`, but hard to know as you gave no indication about the format of that file. Technically `\obeylines` makes very source line a separate paragraph, which complicates disinguishing "real" paragraphs for numbering.

Comment: Thanks for the response David. This is my first ever latex document so I am still trying to fully grasp the options as I go. I have updated the above in line with your recommendations (I hope). Does this help in understanding my question?